# Can Ansible run scripts that execute another script?

Tags: bash, ansible

I'm trying to execute a script using the "script" command in Ansible:

```
- name:tittle
  script: /path/to/script.sh
```

It works fine, but, when the script in question tries to "call" another script (source `./test.sh`) Ansible is not able to find or execute that script.

Converting my script to an Ansible module is not an option.
Is there a way to call another script using a command, or what should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script can call another script, but it has to be present on the host. The script module will automatically upload the script from your control host to the remote host(s). But of course Ansible can not know what other scripts your script might call.

What you can do is to copy your scripts manually with the [copy module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html) before you call the script.

Comment: that´s what i´m gonna do thanks for answering (its works, btw)

Comment: also note ./ may not work, as there's nothing Bruno is doing that specifies a working directory.